# Symfony: render _csrf_token field with sfForm

Tags: symfony1, field, token, csrf

I have a sfForm form `myForm` with another object form embedded in it.

I print it in the template like this:

```
<?php echo $myForm; ?>
```

As far as I know, it's supposed to print the hidden fields by default, but it only prints the `id` hidden field, and not the `_csrf_token`, why is that?

If I try to print it with `echo $myForm['_csrf_token'];` it prints the field just fine.

If I use `echo $myForm->renderHiddenFields();` it prints the `_csrf_token` field and also the `id` hidden field for the second time..

In `myForm` I tried to `enableLocalCSRFProtection()` and it's still doesn't work.

Any idea how to make `myForm` render `_csrf_token` field by default?

Comment: do you have a csrf_secret value set in settings.yml? http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_csrf_secret

Comment: yes. when I use my doctrine forms it works fine.. only sfForm gives me hard time

Comment: unless someone's hacked around the SfFormSymfony class, then I'd think it's coming from the fact that your embedding the form. Maybe try a form without embedding and see if that's indeed the cause. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: OK, thanks! It really was the embedding form that was causing the problem! I have a custom SchemaFormatter which ignores the embedded form's label (cause it's ugly when printing) but I messed up the hidden fields printing... so now it's ok, thanks! :) (write it as an asnwer, I'll accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(placeholder answer, as per comments above)

"It really was the embedding form that was causing the problem! I have a custom SchemaFormatter which ignores the embedded form's label (cause it's ugly when printing) but I messed up the hidden fields printing"